# MS Access 32 bit converting to 64bit error

Tags: ms-access, 32bit-64bit

I wrote an MS Access app in Office 2007 and am now trying to modify it to run on Office 2010 64 bit version.  I get the following error:

The expression On Open you entered as the event property setting produced the following error:  Private Enum and user defined types cannot be used as parameters or return types for public procedures, public data members, or fields of public user defined types.

The error occurs if I try to open a form that has no code in its Open event, so I'm not sure where to start looking to make changes.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

These sort of strange errors can arise if there are broken references. In the database open the VB window, on the menu choose Tools -> References.  In the dialog box the references required will be at the top, check to see if any have "MISSING" prefixing the name.